# 500 Errors not showing specific error

Tags: apache, php

I have updated my `php.ini` files to read as shown below but my 500 page is still not showing errors:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_startup_errors = On
```

This is my VPS and I have the ability to save a 500.shtml file page from cPanel, which I have left blank. Is this getting in the way of displaying errors?  The log file in cPanel shows no errors.

Comment: Why are you expecting your "HTTP 500 error" page to show errors? 500 is the code for a server error, not for a PHP error. See [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: If you're on Apache you can usually find the log file in /var/log/apache2/error.log. This will almost always give you clues to the 500 errors. I know you're using cPanel but many hosts will let you view more detailed logs if you just ask.